# Socket encountered error: undefined in iPhone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, websocket, sentry

I have a `web Socket` to get real time values. While using iPhone devices, we get many errors in guard.
What does it mean? And how can I solve this problem?

These errors do not occur on Android devices. It only happens on iPhone devices.

this is sentry log :
[image]